# From dev to production workflow

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, cicd, continuous-delivery

We are creating micro services environment which needs to be delivered to prod, now we want to start the CICD design, is there any reference which talks about getting from a **Commit ->PR-> tests-> merge -> all the way to production**? I'm not talking about Argo or Flux , we need some reference about the workflow from dev to production, maybe some lesson learned /example...

Comment: The question is pretty broad - feel free to look at my toy project here - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-deployment - it has several links in README with guidance and examples.